# Camera Specs: How change a 16/9 camera render to other ratio?

Tags: rendering, camera

New in the blender community, i've got one question about the camera settings.
Here's my problem, in order to do video mapping on stage for an event, i would like to do a render of my scene in an aspect ratio of 16/10 and not 16/9 (default).

I use the camera on blender as my video projector would stand in real at the event.

Maybe i should use an internal ratio directly on my graphic card, or maybe there is settings that i don't see in blender ?

Hope my english's fine,
Hope that you got answers

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried entering the actual dimensions of the rendered image in the render settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the Properties Panel and open the Output Tab.

Locate the [Dimensions Panel](https://web.archive.org/web/20181118204222/https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/output/output.html). You can set the aspect ratio by setting the X and Y **resultion** of the image.

[image]
<sub>(source: [blender.org](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/_images/render_output_output_dimensions-panel.png))</sub>

For a 16:10 aspect ratio, you could choose the following dimensions: 1920 x 1200.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it work ! It was so obvious that i missed it.

Comment: @StanSch You're welcome, if this answer solves your problem, you can mark it as accepted by clicking the green tick symbol on the top left of the answer.

Comment: Thank you, know i know for sure i will use blender in my workflow. I thought that there was some tools missing, but know i see ! Maybe that i'll post a link of my work.

Comment: You're welcome. Now I only need to teach my [script](https://gist.github.com/Glorfindel83/9d954d34385d2ac2597bbe864466259f) how to do mathematics :P

Comment: But if you use the video editor, the width/height in pixels are the ones to change to stretch/squeeze the final render...

Comment: In 2.8, it is now *Properties > Output > Dimensions*